# mysql saving query to another table

Tags: mysql

How do I save this query to another table within a database so that when a user logs in they can see saved results

```html
SELECT *
FROM sports b 
join sports a
on a.Tag = b.Name
where b.sport_ID <> a.sport_ID and a.Tag = 'football'
```

Comment: If you use a column from `b` in the `WHERE` clause then there's no point in using `LEFT JOIN`, because you'll never got any null values.

Comment: oh right, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the other table has the same schema as the columns returned by your query:

```
INSERT INTO otherTable
SELECT *
FROM sports b 
INNER JOIN sports a
on a.Tag = b.Name
where b.sport_ID <> a.sport_ID and a.Tag = 'football'
```

If the schema isn't the same, you'll need to list the columns explicitly instead of `SELECT *`. There's no way to write "SELECT all columns except Tag` automatically.

Comment: The other table doesn't need to store the tag

Comment: Then you need to list the specific columns to insert into the other table in the `SELECT` list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't save the query to another table. You can save it as a VIEW.